# Is the counterexample for one-to-one function correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

This is one of the question I have been solving from Velleman's `How to Prove` book:

> Suppose $A, B,$ and $C$ are sets and $f : B \to C$.
>
> Suppose that $A \neq \emptyset$ and for all functions $g$ and $h$ from
> $A$ to $B$, if $f \circ g = f \circ h$ then $g = h$. Prove that $f$ is
> one-to-one.

Now while trying to prove this, I have hit upon an counterexample
which shows that $f$ is not actually one to one. Now I think my
counterexample is wrong since this book in my experience rarely
contains any errors. But I'm unable to really understand why my
counterexample is wrong. So here is the counterexample:

$$ A = \{a\}$$
$$ B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4\}$$
$$C = \{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$$

$$g = \{(a,b_1)\}$$
$$   h = \{(a,b_2)\}$$

$$f = \{(b_1, c_1), (b_2, c_2), (b_3, c_3), (b_4, c_3)\}$$

$$f \circ g = \{(a, c_1)\}$$
$$f \circ h = \{(a, c_2)\}$$

Now, $f$ is clearly not one to one. And it also satisfies this
conditional: $g \neq h \implies f \circ g \neq f \circ h$. So what is
wrong in my conclusion that $f$ is not one to one?

Comment: The supposition is that if $f \circ g = f \circ h$ then $g = h$. Isn't this one-to-one by definition? Also, your counter-example has $f$ mapping $b_3$ and $b_4$ to $c_3$. You chose a non-injective function with $f \circ g \neq f \circ h$ as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think are you misreading the exercise.  It asks you to suppose that

$$f\circ g=f\circ h\;\implies \;g=h$$

And, assuming that implication always holds, then show that it implies that $f$ is $1:1$.  To get a counterexample you would have to find a non $1:1$ function for which the desired implication always held.  Your example is not a counterexample.  Were we to take $g=\{(a,b_3)\}$ and $h=\{(a,b_4)\}$ we'd have $f\circ g=f \circ h$ but $g≠h$.

Comment: Applying contrapositve to it I get, $g \neq h \implies f \circ g \neq f \circ h$. But now I have the sets $f, g, f \circ g, f \circ h$ which hold the implication.

Comment: Yes, you have a single instance in which $g≠h$ and $f\circ g≠ f \circ h$.  But to get a counterexample to the exercise you'd have to show that For All $g≠h$ we had $f\circ g≠ f \circ h$, that's the contrapositive.  In my solution I found a particular pair $g≠h$ for which $f\circ g= f \circ h$.

Comment: By the way, what I wrote shows you how to solve the exercise.  If $f$ is not $1:1$ then we must have $f(x)=f(y)$ for some pair $x≠y$.  But in that case suppose that $g$ maps everything to $x$ and $h$ maps everything to $y$.  Then $g≠h$ but $f\circ g= f \circ h$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is one-to-one, then $f(g(x))=f(h(x))$ for all $x\in A$ by the definition means $g(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\in A$.

Now assume $f$ isn't one-to-one, therefore there is exists a $y,z\in B$ such that $y\ne z$ but $f(y)=f(z)$. 
Let $x_0\in A$ satisfy $h(x_0)=z$ . Define $g(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\in A\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $g(x_0)=y$. By construction we have $g\ne h$, but $f(g(x))=f(h(x))$ for all $x\in A$.

Thus the implication $f\circ g =f\circ h \Rightarrow g=h$ for all $g,h:A\rightarrow B$ could happen only if $f$ is one-to-one.